# Asking help with Riemann Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, theorem-provers

i need help with this theoretical exercise with Riemann integration, hope you can help me. Thanks.

Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous  $\vert f\vert$ Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert}{\vert x-y\vert ^2} dxdy < +\infty$$  $f$ turns out to be
constant.

Comment: I'd say this should not be closed as a duplicate, the answers in that question all assume that f is differentiable, while this question only assumes that f is continuous.